# Increase Blogger post content width without affecting sidebar

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger-dynamic-views

I have a blog: [QAValidation](http://qavalidation.com), where I want to increase the blogger post content area (WITHOUT affecting the sidebar gadget's width), 
Please help me how can I widen (increase) the post content width.

[image: Attached screenshot]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not sure about the code (CSS or html) change, that is why I am asking the question here, if anybody faced same issue and solved, so I can leverage the code...